# Change default color of a popupPanel?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a popupPanel:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Simple popup panel" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
            X
        </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
    <p>Any content might be inside this panel.</p>

    <p>
        The popup panel is open and closed from the javascript function of component client side object. The following code
        <a href="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()">hide this panel</a>:
        <f:verbatim>&#35;</f:verbatim>{rich:component('popup')}.hide()
    </p>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

I´m using this example:

[Simple popup example](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=simplePopup&skin=blueSky)

I want to change the color, the default color is blue, I want to change this color to Red or Green, is it possible ?

If it is relevant, i´m using richfaces 4.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's just CSS, have you tried changing it?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it's not work well, I believe i´m not doing correctly

Comment: Well if you don't show us what you tried we can't tell you how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  This css :

```
.rf-pp-hdr{
   background: red;
}
```